# 産業用機器とのTCPソケット通信について

Tags: monaca, tcp

Monacaのみを利用し、産業用機器とTCPソケット通信で接続しコマンドを送信するようなアプリを開発することは可能なのでしょうか？

なお、Websoketを利用したWebサーバとの通信ではなく、三菱のプログラマブルロジックコントローラ (PLC) との、トランスポートプロトコルでのTCPソケット通信を想定しています。

Comment: 重複候補として挙げられている質問には、「Socket通信」を「WebSocket」と解釈した回答しか付いていませんし、その質問者も補足していない所を見ると、それでよいようです。この質問は明確にTCPのレイヤーだと述べているので、重複では無いと思います。

Comment: 「Monacaのみ」のいうのはプラグインなしという意味でしょうか？pure javascriptにTCPソケットを扱う手段がない（Chromeの独自拡張や、flashを利用した手はありますがMonacaでは無理だと思います）ので、ネイティブのプラグインを開発するという方向になるんじゃないんでしょうか。

Comment: @mjy さんにコメントいただいた通り、三菱のPLCとの通信と書かれていたので、重複候補を削除させていただきます。
ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: pure javascriptにTCPソケットを扱う手段はないため、Cordova(PhoneGap)のプラグインをObjective-CやJavaなどのネイティブコードで作成し、それをjavascriptから実行するということですね。また、Cordovaプラグイン組み込みを行うには、Gold以上のプランに加入する必要があるということがわかりました。

[Cordova(PhoneGap)のプラグインの作り方]
http://blog.asial.co.jp/884

Android StudioやXcodeなどで作成した方がいいのか、Gold以上のプラン加入後にプラグイン組み込みをした方がいいのか考えてみたいと思います。

この度は回答を頂き、ありがとうございました。

Comment: プラグインを作っている方はいるようですね（https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova）。目的に合うかは分かりませんが。

Comment: mjyさん、貴重な情報を頂き、ありがとうございます。まずはGoldのお試し期間で確認してみたいと思います。